# Will it be bad to use a very high value for padding-bottom and very low value for margin-bottom in order to make divs match heights

Tags: css

[Here is my jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QtTeA/)The specific CSS I am referring to is on the selector `.inner div`. By 'will it be bad,' I mean, would you use it on your page? Do you foresee any problems with it? Is there a name for this technique? Is there a better way to accomplish this? My goal was to make the two `div`s floated left `#one` and `#two` to match heights, and as you can see, the aqua color on the left one is stretching all the way to the bottom of the `section`.

html

```
<section>
    <div class="inner">
    <div id="one"><p>Lorem</p></div>
    <div id="two">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

css

```
section {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#one, #two {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#one {
    background: aqua;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner div {
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Jeeeeeez, I'd say even using a `table` would be nicer than that :)

Comment: But then I want the divs to stack on top of each other if the screen size is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not great, plus if that text ever changes size, you'll have to adjust your CSS.

Instead, remove that padding and margin, give the whole `.inner` a background of aqua, but change the background of `#two` to be white.

Here's what I changed in the fiddle:

```
#two {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.inner {
    background: aqua;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QtTeA/1/

Comment: Sweet, that seems more legit.

Comment: @sherlock Glad I could help :). Just call me watson!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it does feel nasty, I wouldn't do it. I'd personally just use a

```
min-height:1000px /* Or whatever height */
```

on each DIV, its a lot more flexible. The moment you put any content in #one it will become longer than #two

Comment: What if the text changes though? The CSS also needs updating, not exactly an ideal solution :)

Comment: I don't want them that high, just enough to fit what's inside.

Comment: What is going to be going in the aqua DIV? Maybe use a combo of my answer and the other answer on this page